# Use of "me and girlfriend"

Tags: pronouns, ellipsis

> As a musical experience, Eddie Howlloway Live at the Silver Lounge was
>   a jolt. Two songs, originals, were vehicles for Eddie to describe,
>   simply and sincerely, his enormous lovemaking abilities. These didn't
>   interest me except as examples of fine lyrics and vocal delivery.
>   Three other originals, however, provoked me in other ways. These not
>   only referred to me by name, but described my lifestyle ("dull as a
>   mole in his dark hole"), career ("he strikes a pose, this writer of
>   indifferent prose"), and way with women ("slick and insincere, don't
>   let him call you dear") in outrageous terms. Here then was another
>   artist who, like Kelly, was able and willing to insert personal notes
>   about **me and girlfriend** into his music, to make a point. But while
>   Kelly's personal references were true, as I myself had verified,
>   Eddie's were false as could be. Both artists, however, were true song
>   stylists who succeeded in making genuine music. I couldn't overlook
>   that, for all my personal involvement in their sounds.
>
> *The dangerous singers* by Michael Fowler

Why is the possessive pronoun 'my' omitted in front of *girlfriend* here? Does it sound colloquial?

Comment: Yes - it sounds colloquial because it *is* colloquial to omit the determiner (***my, a***, or more rarely ***the***) in such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see. Another Q here (too trivial to open a new Q): *personal notes* here mean musical notes with the artist's personal style or personal information about individuals?

Comment: I'd say it's probably just coincidence that the writer happened to use ***notes*** in a "musical" context. But regardless of whether it might have been a deliberate "pun", *personal notes* here simply means *personal **details / anecdotes / references*** (concerning the writer and his girlfriend, such that *they* will recognise the allusions, even if no-one else does).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is it natural to produce a sentence like "he added notes about my friend to his novel/speech/website"?

Comment: No. But it wouldn't be any more natural if you changed it to "He added notes about my friend to his song". It's "sorta" reasonable to use ***notes*** in the context cited above, because the entire text is somewhat "stylised", but it's unlikely Fowler would actually *talk* like this in any normal conversational context. Most people in most contexts would refer to *personal **details***.